# What does it mean "cursed of God"?

Tags: deuteronomy

In Deuteronomy 21:22-23

> 22 “Now if a person has committed a sin carrying a sentence of death and he is put to death, and you hang him on a tree, 23 his body is not to be left overnight on the tree, but you shall certainly bury him on the same day (for he who is hanged is **cursed of God**), so that you do not defile your land which the Lord your God is giving you as an inheritance.

What does it mean "cursed of God"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NASB 1977 Deuteronomy 21:23

> his corpse shall not hang all night on the tree, but you shall surely bury him on the same day (for he who is hanged is **accursed of God**), so that you do not defile your land which the LORD your God gives you as an inheritance.

That person is under a curse inflicted by God. This verse is fulfilled by Jesus on the cross.

> Jesus who is hanged on the cross is accursed by God.

Galatians 3:13

> Christ redeemed us from the **curse of the law** by becoming a **curse** for us, for it is written: "**Cursed** is everyone who is hung on a pole."

The law is a curse in the sense that it condemns us all to death. Jesus died on the cross becoming a curse for us. The law could not condemn Jesus. According to the law, he was not supposed to die. God made Jesus a curse for us by dying on the cross according to Deuteronomy 21:23. Jesus' sacrificial act undid the curse of the law for those who believe. Now, we are no longer under the curse of the law.